# Error while trying to migrate from sqlite to MySQL in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, python-2.7

I was using sqlite as my database for Django application. I have created several models and everything was working fine. I tried to migrate to MySQL for production. So I installed MySQL server, created database and changed the settings file correctly.

When I issue command `python manage.py makemigrations` it shows `No changes detected` and then I issued `python manage.py migrate`, I am getting following error. Some table are created on the database, but its not completely migrated.

Here is the error shown when I enter `python manage.py migrate`

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: users, sessions, admin, auth, contenttypes, result, questions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying questions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying questions.0002_studentresponse... OK
  Applying questions.0003_auto_20150625_1734... OK
  Applying questions.0004_remove_questions_sections... OK
  Applying questions.0005_questions_sections... OK
  Applying result.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying users.0001_initial... OK
  Applying users.0002_auto_20150603_1042...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 43, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 398, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'paymentData'")
```

Please check this.

Comment: Can you paste the outcome from manage.py sqlmigrate users 0002_auto_20150603_1042?

Comment: Please provide the models file which contains the field 'paymentData'

Comment: @Ymartin
`paymentData = models.CharField(max_length =20)` and its a part of user profile

Comment: @valtuarte I am getting following outcome
     BEGIN;
     ALTER TABLE `users_userprofile` DROP COLUMN `permission` CASCADE;
     ALTER TABLE `users_userprofile` ADD COLUMN `paymentData` varchar(20) DEFAULT 2015-06-03 10:42:03.237469+00:00 NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `users_userprofile` ALTER COLUMN `paymentData`  DROP DEFAULT;

     COMMIT;

Comment: Is your mysql pointing to the same database as sqlite?

Comment: @Ymartin Sorry, how can I know that?

Comment: when you were using sqlite, what was the name of the DB? and what is the name of the DB now? Is it same?

Comment: @Ymartin I am a bit confused, when I used sqlite, its file name was `db.sqlite3`. I have created MySQL database name as `testdatabase`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87375/discussion-between-ymartin-and-nitroman).

Comment: What if deleting/moving the migrations folder?

Comment: There are two options. 1)You can delete the migrations and again create another migrations folder just with `__init__.py` file. Then run your migrations 2) Or lookup django `--fake` migrations